# Cannot create instance of 'Ribbon'

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, exception, .net-3.5, ribbon

I'm having trouble using the Ribbon control from the Office 2007 RibbonControlsLibrary.dll.

It works for most people but not for me. The fault I get is:

Cannot create instance of 'Ribbon' defined in assembly 'RibbonControlsLibrary, Version=3.5.31016.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

The problem is probably not with the code since it works for other people.
Its the Ribbon class thats causing the problem. If I remove any references to the Ribbon class but keep the references to RibbonWindow I don't get any exceptions.

Any help appreciated

Comment: If your InnerException is not null, what are its contents? A "thrown by target of an invocation" exception is almost always a "wrapper" exception around the real one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it...
My problem was that RibbonControlsLibrary.dll was in the GAC... as soon as I removed it from the GAC it worked like a charm...